# React table row delete does not remove the TextInput

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting a book list from database and is stored in a state variable Book list also has book price field

```
const [books, setBooks]=useState([])
setBooks(data)
```

I am creating an html in a loop based on the above books data

```
return ( <div>
{books.map((x,i) => ( <tr>
                         <td>x.bookName</td>
                         <td><MyCustomTextInput value={x.price}></MyCustomTextInput></td>
                      <tr></div>);
```

MyCustomTextInput looks like as follows

```
function MyCustomTextInput(props)
     { return (<div>><TextInput></TextInput> </div>) 
     } exports default MyCustomTextInput
```

I have a button after clicked, it adds a new book entry in the array which also displays a new row in the table

When I remove an item from an array, the table also removes the row which is correct and expected

BUT lets say there are 5 rows in the table. Row ID 4 has Text Input value say $23.32 and Row ID 5 has Text Input Value as $30.00 then after the row 4 is deleted, price from the row 4 which was before delete $23.32 stays as it is even after row 5 is now row 4 and I am expecting to see price $30.00 (row 5 is now moved to row 4 place after delete)

This issue is only with the Text Input and another field book name in the table gets changed properly

Experts any suggestions .....

Comment: I think you put the wrong code in your MyCustomTextInput snippet, can you check it and put the right code to be able to help you more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using lists React expects a "key" prop so that when an a child e.g. a book is deleted it knows which one was deleted

I am having a hard time following your code but your books should like this in the list:

```
<tr key={book.id}>
    <td>whatever</td>
</tr>
```

now when the tr with the key of {some id} at index 4 for example is deleted react will update the list correctly

Comment: Thank you Ahmed, will try adding a key and update you on this

Comment: Thank you Ahmed, I am accepting your answer as I feel you are the first to comment. Really appreciate your and other contributors help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should make clear about your problem. Lots of typo errors make it difficult to understand your real problem.

The only thing I can guess now is that it can be related to map function

```
books.map((x,i) => ( <tr key={x.id}> ... </tr>)
```

You should add `key` attribute to `tr` element to tell `react` which one is newly created.

And I am not sure about this one.

```
function MyCustomTextInput(props)
     { return (<div>><MyCustomTextInput></MyCustomTextInput> </div>) 
     } exports default MyCustomTextInput
```

You are rendering `MyCustomTextInput` in a `MyCustomTextInput` component?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, It was a typo, I have corrected the code. I am rendering TextInput inside MyCustomTextInput.

Comment: I am checking more on adding an ID to the row and will update you

Comment: Just using `i` as a key cause such error. Check it and make sure you use `item`'s `id` as a key. `<tr key={x.id}> `, not `<tr key={i}>`

Comment: thank you very much for providing the answer. I have accepted the answer for this post. Appreciate your help.